# Customize Users inside Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add some fields in Users section, apart from the predefined ones. I want to add a section called "Objectives" and also another called "Tests".

How can I do this? [image]

Comment: Have you defined `Objectives` and `Tests` in User model?

Comment: You need to also show us your effort, I mean your attempt to implement what you're looking for.

Comment: Where will that data be stored? Do you have a custom user model?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM No yet I have been reading abput extend User Model but I'm not 100% sure how to that.

Comment: @ettanany Of course, I don't want the code itself just a guidance in how can I achieve this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman

As I said before I have been reading some articles about extend User Model but I don't know if that will work for this situation. I want my info stored in the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,
class Publisher(AbstractUser):

    legal_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    website = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1024)
    objects = UserManager()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'publisher'
    verbose_name_plural = 'publishers'
```

and in admin use code below:

```
class PublisherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
     fields = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'legal-user']
```